# Fastest Way to combine 2d arrays and then Sort by index 0

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, multidimensional-array

For problems like this, I would set up a `loop push` to combine these into one 2d array then I would use `.filter` to sort the info.  I feel like this is inefficient and there should be a better way.  My data set isn't huge but 50,000+ rows with 90 columns seems to take a little time to compile. What would be the fastest way to combine these 2d arrays into one sorted 2d array?

```
  var array1 = [[1/1/21,1B,1C,1D,1E,1F,1G,1H,1I,1J,1K,1L],
                [1/2/21,2B,2C,2D,2E,2F,2G,2H,2I,2J,2K,2L],
                [1/2/21,3B,3C,3D,3E,3F,3G,3H,3I,3J,3K,3L],
                [4/1/21,4B,4C,4D,4E,4F,4G,4H,4I,4J,4K,4L]]
  
  var array2 = [[2/1/21,5B,5C,5D,5E,5F,5G,5H,5I,5J,5K,5L],
                [2/2/21,6B,6C,6D,6E,6F,6G,6H,6I,6J,6K,6L]]
  
  var array3 = [[1/1/21,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,7G,7H,7I,7J,7K,7L],
                [1/15/21,8B,8C,8D,8E,8F,8G,8H,8I,8J,8K,8L],
                [2/1/21,9B,9C,9D,9E,9F,9G,9H,9I,9J,9K,9L]]
  
  var desiredResult = [[1/1/21,1B,1C,1D,1E,1F,1G,1H,1I,1J,1K,1L],
                       [1/1/21,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,7G,7H,7I,7J,7K,7L],
                       [1/2/21,2B,2C,2D,2E,2F,2G,2H,2I,2J,2K,2L],
                       [1/2/21,3B,3C,3D,3E,3F,3G,3H,3I,3J,3K,3L],
                       [1/15/21,8B,8C,8D,8E,8F,8G,8H,8I,8J,8K,8L],
                       [2/1/21,5B,5C,5D,5E,5F,5G,5H,5I,5J,5K,5L],
                       [2/1/21,9B,9C,9D,9E,9F,9G,9H,9I,9J,9K,9L],
                       [2/2/21,6B,6C,6D,6E,6F,6G,6H,6I,6J,6K,6L],
                       [4/1/21,4B,4C,4D,4E,4F,4G,4H,4I,4J,4K,4L]]
```

Comment: Look up the [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) methods for the Array class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Explanation:**

- Use [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to merge all the arrays:

  ```
  const desiredResult = array1.concat(array2,array3);
  ```
- Use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and sort by date:

  ```
  desiredResult.sort( (a,b) => new Date(a[0]) - new Date(b[0]));
  ```

### **Solution:**

```
const desiredResult = array1.concat(array2,array3);
desiredResult.sort( (a,b) => new Date(a[0]) - new Date(b[0]))
```

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

```js
const array1 = [["1/1/21","1B","1C"],
                ["1/2/21","2B","2C","2D"],
                ["1/2/21","3B","3C","3D"],
                ["4/1/21","4B","4C","4D"]];
  
const array2 = [["2/1/21","5B","5C","5D"],
                ["2/2/21","6B","6C","6D"]];
  
const array3 = [["1/1/21","7B","7C","7D"],
                ["1/15/21","8B","8C","8D"],
                ["2/1/21","9B","9C","9D"]];
const desiredResult = array1.concat(array2,array3);
desiredResult.sort( (a,b) => new Date(a[0]) - new Date(b[0]))                
console.log(desiredResult);
```